# Python telebot infinity-polling

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot, telebot

hope you all be right.

I am creating a telegram bot using python, I want to know if there is a way to run a function each time before the infinity-polling starts.

I have search for it almost for 2 days and found nothing.

I searched all arguments that  infinity-polling would take bot none of them were what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are searching for the post_init method of the ApplicationBuilder.
With it you can define a method to be executed after executing Application.initialize() but before executing Updater.start_polling().
The post_init method expects the method you want to call, and the method you want to be called must have one parameter of type Application.

https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.applicationbuilder.html#telegram.ext.ApplicationBuilder.post_init

Comment: Thank you bro but i dont think the anser you have given to me is the library that i am using...

iam using this : https://pypi.org/project/telebot/

Comment: Ah ok sorry, i just searched the tag, and didn't looked at the title.
The only Idea i now have is to wrap a TeleBot.send_message() method before the infinity_polling() method in an own method, and call this method everytime you want to start polling. but not sure if it is possible to use the bot outside of polling, since i don't have worked with this libary

Comment: Np bro, thanks a million.